# Access - conditional statement

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

Coming from the excel world, how to I create a conditional statement to populate one field based on the value on the other, something that in excel would look like:

```
=if(A1="A","Yes","No")
```

Thank you

EDIT:

Ok, I've done the following:

```
=IIF([FundingStream]="A", "N/A", "Student Finance")
```

But I've got an error:
Invalid SQL syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level CHECK constraint

I'm entering this expression in the Validation Rule of the properties of a Field that N/A or Student Finance should appear.

EDIT 2:

I've done as suggested below. When I type in the FundingStream, it does not change the LoanCRN field at all. See the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Is this supposed to be in VBA, a form, a query?  In VBA: "If xxx = "A" then yyy = "Yes" Else yyy = "No" End IF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they can serve some of the same purposes, relational databases system require a different paradigm.  The simple idea of setting one column value based on another is actually rather complex when compared to a spreadsheet.  You will only face continued frustration if you try to convert your spreadsheet literally.

The following statement in a Validation Rule is *not an assignment*, rather it is a Boolean comparison operation:  It returns true or false.  It constrains the values which can be saved to the database, but it does not change the column values.

```
[Field1] = Iif([FundingStream]="A", "N/A", "Student Finance")
```

As a further side note, some languages have two different symbols for assignment and comparison, for instance `:=` for assignment and `==` for equality comparison.  But many languages, like VBA, interpret a single `=` based on context.  If you understand the difference, the context usually becomes apparent what the equal sign means in a particular case.

To change the values of one field based on another requires other techniques.  The flexibility of any code or macro driven environment, like Access, provide various ways of doing this that can't all be outlined here.  However, the two most obvious that come to mind are:

### VBA code in a form module

Probably the most direct way of doing this is in the AfterUpdate event:

```
Private Sub FundingStream_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.FundingStream = "A" Then
        Me.LoanCRN = "N/A"
    Else
        Me.LoanCRN = "Student Finance"
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that you at least have two controls on your form:  FundingStream and LoanCRN.  This will do what you want... initially.  However, now you would need to consider whether the user can also update LoanCRN directly.  If they should never update LoanCRN directly, you could either 1) set the control property `Locked = True`, or 2) hide the control on the form so the user can't even see it, or 3) eliminate the actual control and just reference the record source column property directly, like `Me![LoanCRN]`.  More details for any of those techniques is beyond this question.

But that's not all!  You need to consider appropriate default values.  What happens if the user never actually changes the FundingStream control?  Then your code would never run and so LoanCRN might not be set properly. In the end, it is likely that you will need further code elsewhere on the form, e.g. in Form_AfterUpdate(), Form_Current, etc.

The benefit to this approach is that you have all the flexibility of the data entry form to shape exactly how you want the data to flow.  The difficulty is in avoiding missing and conflicting behavior on the form.  This technique ultimately requires appropriate use of table and column constraints (i.e. Validation Rules and indexes) and familiarity with form and control events.

This also only works for the particular form.  If you have other forms or VBA code that change the FundingStream value, you would also need to add the same code in all those locations to ensure LoanCRN value is always valid.

### Before Change Data Macro

Define a Before Change macro on the table to update values.  Use `If` and `SetField` macro actions to set LoanCRM based on FundingStream.

From a naive perspective, this is actually the most direct, easy way to do it.  The Data Macro is called automatically **every time a record is saved**, no matter if it is updated on a form or in VBA code.

This also has many restrictions and does not allow flexibility of adding many dynamic conditions, especially conditions present at data entry.  *If your macro logic is not robust, it can cause unnecessary errors that prevent the entire set of data from being saved.*

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'm probably missing some other obvious thing. Sorry. Am new to access. I have updated the questions. Please see above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. On a generic note, I need to switch from thinking in Excel terms about Access.